# how to use multiple database in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I have two project, first one in Yii and another in Open cart, I need use both DB in a project, in Yii site I have complete, now I have a issue in open cart so please explain how to use multiple database in open cart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple database something like this:

```
 // Define database
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db1 = 'username1';
    $pwd = 'pass';

    $db2 = 'user2';
    $pwd2 = 'pass';

    $con1 = mysql_connect($host, $db1, $pwd) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
    $con2 = mysql_connect($host, $db2, $pwd2) or die ('2nd Db Error connecting to mysql');

    $db_name1 = '`mydatabase`';
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $con1);

    $db_name2 = '`mydatabase2`';
    mysql_select_db($db_name2, $con2);
```

This is your database actions:

```
    $result = mysql_query("Select * from ......", $con1) or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("Select * from ......", $con2) or die(mysql_error());
```